# Mission control and SplitView keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-sierra

I'm using Sierra, is there a option to while in mission control, alternate the selection between apps with keyboard only, without using the mouse or trackpad?
Also is there an option to change from normal view to split view with keyboard only, pick a windows (with keyboard too) and go back to normal view?

Answer (score 0):

To switch between app you could use 
`cmd + tab`

To switch in Mission control between the desks you could use
`ctrl + arrowskeys`

There is not way to open split view just with the keyboard.

Comment: what do you mean by tap? trackpad / mouse tap?